# Could not load controller 'smart_arm_controller', why?

Tags: microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following parameter on the server:

```
 /smart_arm/smart_arm_controller/type =
      robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController
```

and in a launch file I do

```
 node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" ns="/smart_arm" args="smart_arm_controller
                                              shoulder_pan_controller
                                                       ....
```

then why do I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] [1428415830.676479048, 0.952000000]: Could not load controller 'smart_arm_controller' because controller type 'robot_mechanism_controllers/JointTrajectoryActionController' does not exist.
```

Note that I do have the package robot_mechanism_controllers installed.

I am at a loss here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206763/could-not-load-controller-%27smart_arm_controller%27,-why?/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer my own question. I should have used the package pr2_controller_manager.

That didn't work either, but I'll ask another question about that.

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-11-30**:
have you resolved this?

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2017-11-30**:
I currently use as type:  joint_state_controller/JointStateController
this works fine now. This is on kinetic